# Facebook like box is not working, why is that?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am trying to implement facebook's like box to a site I am creating atm, but it is simply not working. I inserted the needed code, and nothing is being shown on my site.
I am using localhost to test my webpage, this is the code:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/foofighters" data-width="175" data-height="250" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

PS: I am not developing a site for the Foo Fighters, it is just a "dummy" site atm xd

Comment: Are you using a `file://` URL?

Comment: yes, I am using a file:// URL

Comment: In my case I had `Disconnect` firefox addon installed. Took me 4 hours to figure out that it was the cause (had forgotten its existence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

instead of

```
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

try:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/foofighters" data-width="175" data-height="250" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's certainly a start.

Comment: Thanks, and it wont work on localhost (wamp) for some reason so I will upload it to a free host to test it o.o

Comment: Good luck, let us know the results.

Comment: i suggest not adding the protocol to the url, that´s bad practice

Comment: it is really starting to get on my nerves, it won't work even on a free webhost o.O

Comment: OMG Guys, firefox is playing with me, in Internet Explorer it is fine jesus xD

Comment: works for me even in firefox :) - and again, do NOT add the protocol to the url, and check the browser console for errors if it does not work.

Comment: okay thanks. I am always having problems with firefox for some reason lol